# Using an "or" statement inside a "if" statement with a string length method

Tags: java, if-statement

So in my fifth line of code `[if(length == 2 || 1)]` I'm getting an error with my or statement saying the Operator || is undefined for the argument types boolean, int. Any ideas on what is wrong with my syntax and how I can fix it? Thanks!

```
//Write a program that translates a letter grade into a number grade. Letter grades are
//A B C D F, possibly followed by + or -. Their numeric values are 4, 3, 2, 1, and 0.
//There is no F+ or F-. A + increases the numeric value by 0.3, a - decreases it by     0.3.
//However, an A+ has the value 4.0. All other inputs have value –1.
//Enter a letter grade:
```

//Use a class Grade with a method getNumericGrade.

```
public class Grade {
private double grade = 0.0;
public double getNumericGrade(String letterGrade){
    int length = letterGrade.length();
    if(length == 2 || 1){
        char startChar = letterGrade.charAt(0);
        char endChar = letterGrade.charAt(1);
        switch(startChar){
        case 'A':
            this.grade = 4.0;
            break;
        case 'B':
            this.grade = 3.0;
            break;
        case 'C':
            this.grade = 2.0;
            break;
        case 'D':
            this.grade = 1.0;
            break;
        case 'F':
            this.grade = 0.0;
            break;
        default:
            this.grade = -1;
        }
    if(length == 2){
        switch(endChar){
        case '-':
            this.grade = this.grade - .3;
            break;
        case '+':
            if(startChar != 'A'){
            this.grade = this.grade + .3;
            }
            break;
        default:
            this.grade = -1;
        }
    }
    if(startChar == 'F' && length != 1){
        this.grade = -1;
    }
    }else{
        this.grade = -1;
    }
    return this.grade;
}
```

}

Comment: Should be `length == 2 || length == 1`.  Can't do a 2 for 1 in a conditional.

Answer (score 3):

It means that the `||` operator doesn't take a boolean and an int, you have to give it two boolean expressions.

```
if(length == 2 || length ==  1)
```

Comment: +1 for speed (there are two types of people: The quick, and the have-nots)

Answer (score 1):

You want to be saying if(length == 1 || length == 2). What you're doing right now is saying if(length == 2 OR 1). The former involves two logical statements that can evaluate true or false, the latter involves a logical statement on the one hand and an integer on the other.

The computer doesn't interpret length == 2 OR 1 as "return true if length is either one or two" but as "(return true if length equals two) or (the integer 1)".

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
if (Arrays.asList(1,2,3).contains(l.lenghth))
   // code
```

Comment: It's not wrong, it's just not ***great***. Generally the more effort you put into it the more reward. I saw that you were new so I redirected you to a page telling you specifically the dos and don'ts of this site.

Comment: Ahhh...yes...Nevertheless I guess I couldn't write more to support that would support my answer because it's just one trivial line of code